# Find Class.Type from CoreData entity.managedObjectClassName

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a method that receives a class type:

```
public static func download<T:NSManagedObject>(_ classType:T.Type){
    ...
}
```

And I need to call this method from a place where I only have an `NSEntityDescription` available, so a basically only have a `managedObjectClassName` String available (as far as I know).

I tried the following code:

```
let entityClass = NSClassFromString(entity.managedObjectClassName) as? NSManagedObject.Type
```

But then I get a reference to the `NSManagedObject` class, and I need to access the child's static properties

Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: This has been a while. Did you find a solution in the meantime? I have the same problem. Thanks.